# Ajax url not working in magento1.9 under Adminhtml folder of custom module

Tags: magento-1.9

Ajax url not working in magento1.9 under Adminhtml folder of custom module tried many method but still not work for me.

```
function getsubcategories(cat_id){ 
    $j.ajax({
        type : 'GET',          
        url:'<?php echo $this->getUrl('modulename/Adminhtml_controllername/function_name/?category_id='+cat_id); ?>',
        success:function(data){ 
            console.log(data);
            //~ var returnedData = JSON.parse(data);
            //~ alert(returnedData);

            //~ var str='';
            //~ $.each(returnedData, function(key, value) {

                //~ str=str + '<option value='+key+'>'+value+'</option>';
            //~ });
            //~ $('#subcategory').html(str);
         }
    });
}
```

Please tell me how to pass controller's function name in URL

Comment: Can you precise what you tried ? [ask]

Comment: Static Url, magento key based url

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $this->getUrl(), you can try

```
Mage::getUrl('modulename/Adminhtml_controllername/function_name/?category_id='+cat_id');
```

And you can this function in your controller

```
protected function _isAllowed() {

      return true;
}
```